# R - Merging data of different frequencies

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes that I am trying to merge. One is daily data with days missing (but at least one observation for each month). The other is monthly data (with no months missing). They both span the same time frame.

I would like to merge the data by month (i.e. the month-year of the daily data corresponding with the month-year of the monthly data), keeping the higher frequency.

```
df1 = daily data (unequal frequency ... i.e. missing days)
df2 = monthly data (equal frequency)

merge(df1, df2) ???

df1.date df1.x df2.y
1/1/2005 5.5 10
1/2/2005 5.9 10
1/5/2005 6.5 10
...
11/2/2005 2.5 12
11/4/2005 3.9 12
11/6/2005 1.3 12
...
```

Is there anyway to do this in R? (I have been struggling with zoo and ts and haven't found anything even close ... hence this post).

Comment: Give us some of your data to work on.  I would suggest converting your daily data (assuming you know the date) to the month of the year, this will give two data sets with months that should be easy to merge.

Comment: Can provide a sample of the two data sets.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure both data sets have `month` and `year` columns, then `merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @user1945827 & @Gregor

I was making a mountain out of a molehill.

As you suggested, all that I needed to do was to create a common index for both datasets to merge on:

```
lo$monthyear <- format(lo$ListingCreationDate, format='%B-%Y')
ue$monthyear <- format(ue$Month, format='%B-%Y')

lonew <- data.frame(merge(lo, ue, by="monthyear"))
```

I am posting this as an answer because I literally spent hours using different packages trying to accomplish something that a one sentence answer resolved. Hopefully it will be useful to someone else.